# In a grouped SQL query, efficiently discard groups that have or do not have some values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having, any

I am trying to construct a query that aggregates records in a table while filtering out groups based on constraints that involve the presence or absence of certain values in one of the columns. Here is some example data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
person_id smallint,
position_id smallint
);

INSERT INTO test 
VALUES (1, 30), (1, 99), (1, 98), (2, 98), (2, 99), (3, 30), (3, 28);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

```
+-----------+-------------+
| person_id | position_id |
+-----------+-------------+
|         1 |          30 |
|         1 |          99 |
|         1 |          98 |
|         2 |          98 |
|         2 |          99 |
|         3 |          30 |
|         3 |          28 |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to aggregate this over person_id, but only for persons who have position 30, and do not have position 28 (for example). The correct query result should be:

```
+-----------+------------+
| person_id | positions  |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | 30, 99, 98 |
+-----------+------------+
```

The question is, **how to do this efficiently?** The actual table I will be doing this on is larger.

I have two working queries that get the correct result:

```sql
SELECT person_id, Group_concat(position_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS positions
FROM test
GROUP BY person_id 
HAVING Sum(CASE WHEN position_id = 30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
AND Sum(CASE WHEN position_id = 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;

SELECT person_id, Group_concat(position_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS positions
FROM test
GROUP BY person_id 
HAVING Max(position_id = 30) = 1
AND Max(position_id = 28) = 0;
```

However, it seems to me that it shouldn't be necessary to actually do the full aggregations (with `Sum()` or `Max()`) for each group, like these queries do, and that it would be more efficient to reformulate this using logical 'any' conditions. E.g.

- the first time I encounter a '30' position_id, I have satisfied the first condition;
- the first time I encounter a '28' position_id, I have failed the second condition;

there is no need to proceed through the rest of the position_id's for a group after that. However, I'm not sure how to do that, and maybe I am in any case on the wrong track here.

This is using MySQL 8.

Comment: add this: `WHERE person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM test WHERE position_id=30) AND  
 person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM test WHERE position_id=28)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT person_id, Group_concat(position_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS positions
from test t
WHERE EXISTS  ( SELECT person_id 
                     FROM test t1 
                     WHERE t.person_id=t1.person_id
                     AND t1.position_id=30 
                   ) 
AND  NOT EXISTS  (  SELECT person_id 
                     FROM test t2 
                     WHERE t.person_id=t2.person_id
                     AND t2.position_id=28  )
GROUP BY person_id ;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> person_id positions
>     1     30, 99, 98
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0ea3c768d489c02b67f06218ef4e0ec3)

Comment: That did the trick, about 2-5 times faster on the need case I have. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could try using a subquery to identify if the person matches your constraints.

```sql
SELECT person_id, Group_concat(position_id SEPARATOR ', ') AS positions
FROM test
WHERE 28 NOT IN (
  SELECT position_id
  FROM test AS ti
  WHERE ti.person_id = test.person_id
) AND 30 IN (
  SELECT position_id
  FROM test AS ti
  WHERE ti.person_id = test.person_id
)
GROUP BY person_id;
```

However as long as you don't analyze the query execution plan any performance improvement is only guessing.